# How to stop perl buffering ffmpeg output

Tags: perl, ffmpeg

I am trying to have a Perl program process the output of an ffmpeg encode, however my test program only seems to receive the output of ffmpeg in periodic chunks, thus I am assuming there is some sort of buffering going on. How can I make it process it in real-time?

My test program (the `tr` command is there because I thought maybe ffmpeg's carriage returns were causing perl to see one big long line or something):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$i = "test.mkv"; # big file, long encode time
$o = "test.mp4";

open(F, "-|", "ffmpeg -y -i '$i' '$o' 2>&1 | tr '\r' '\n'")
        or die "oh no";

while(<F>) {
        print "A12345: $_"; # some random text so i know the output was processed in perl
}
```

Everything works fine when I replace the `ffmpeg` command with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello";

for i in `seq 1 10`; do
        sleep 1;
        echo "hello $i";
done

echo "bye";
```

When using the above script I see the output each second as it happens. With `ffmpeg` it is some 5-10 seconds or so until it outputs and will output sometimes 100 lines each output.

I have tried using the program `unbuffer` ahead of `ffmpeg` in the command call but it seems to have no effect. Is it perhaps the `2>&1` that might be buffering?
Any help is much appreciated.

If you are unfamiliar with ffmpeg's output, it outputs a bunch of file information and stuff to `STDOUT` and then during encoding it outputs lines like

```
frame=  332 fps= 93 q=28.0 size=     528kB time=00:00:13.33 bitrate= 324.2kbits/s speed=3.75x
```

which begin with carriage returns instead of new lines (hence `tr`) on `STDERR` (hence `2>&1`).

Comment: Try `open(F,'-|:unix',"ffmpeg......")`

Comment: @ChankeyPathak I tried adding :unix but it unfortunately doesn't seem any different.

Comment: @SebastianKing: Do you understand what `2>&1` does? Why did you put it there?

Comment: As it stands, your `ffmpeg` command will take `test.mkv` and convert it to `test.mp4`. Yes, I'm avoiding the question, but do you really need real-time access to the progress of the conversion?

Comment: @Borodin I think so, see the bottom of my question where I explained why I am using it. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @SebastianKing: You're running on a Windows system, right?

Comment: @Borodin No, ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I am running perl in my bash shell.

Comment: @SebastianKing: I'm familiar with `ffmpeg`, but I don't see anything in your question that tells me why you need to see the output in real time. That output is meant for console use, and if you're running the conversion by program then surely you just need to know whether each file was converted successfully?

Comment: I'm surprised that `ffmpeg` adds CR to its line endings on a Linux build, but there's no reason to remove them. Use just `ffmpeg -y -i '$i' '$o' | unbuffer`

Comment: It's a "trick" used to update the current line. // They can't use `<>` if they don't replace them. (Which is fine; they could use `read` instead.) // That's not how one uses `unbuffer`.

Comment: @Borodin see comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027563/how-to-stop-perl-buffering-ffmpeg-output?noredirect=1#comment71230904_42027563 for why I want a real-time output. The carriage returns let you watch the status of the encode in a normal human terminal without clogging up the screen etc.

Comment: @SebastianKing: Sure, but my question remains, why do you want to see "live stats"? It's not like someone can leap in, fix the source video, and let the train keep on running. Isn't this just like watching the washing machine rotate?

Comment: @Borodin I have always had live stats, only I have recently translated my program from bash to perl and now perl is no longer able to update in real-time.

Comment: @SebastianKing: So you don't really need them. How about decluttering your brain? Did you try piping the output of `ffmpeg` to `unbuffer` and dropping `tr`? It's much easier to translate characters within Perl.

Comment: @Borodin My live stats are staying, I will find a solution one way or another. `unbuffer` cannot be piped to, the correct use is `unbuffer <bin> <args>`. When I do it that way, I get a real-time output up until the carriage return section where I get no output until the encode has finished. That's why I have the `tr` but the problem does seem to be there now that we look at it.

Comment: @SebastianKing: I'm sorry. Use `unbuffer -p`

Comment: @Borodin using `unbuffer -p <bin> <args>` doesn't seem to have helped

Comment: @SebastianKing: I'm sorry, I was unclear. The `-p` option enables reading from stdin (hence `-p` for "pipe"). Try `ffmpeg -y -i '$i' '$o' | unbuffer -p`

Comment: What I would prefer is a Perl way of falsifying a terminal data sink when opening a pipe from a program. It's not such an unlikely requirement.

Comment: @Borodin the only options that `unbuffer` gives me are `-console, -ignore, -leaveopen, -noecho, -nottycopy, -nottyinit, -open, or -pty` and if I try `echo "hi" | unbuffer -pty` it just hangs with no output.

Comment: @SebastianKing: Then I'm sorry, I can't help. I've used it occasionally on various systems and it's documented [on `linuxcommand.org`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html)

Comment: @Borodin I checked `man unbuffer` on my system and `-p` is mentioned. I was using it incorrectly as I was trying it without the trailing `tr` as `-p` still requires a `<bin>` argument. Using `ffmpeg <...>  | unbuffer -p tr '\r' '\n'` appears to have the desired results. Thank you very much. It was by using `unbuffer --help` that I got the list of available options which I suppose does not include short options..

Comment: @Borodin If you would care to create an answer I would be more than happy to accept it. I have also replaced `unbuffer -p` with `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -eL` (`-eL` so it's now line buffered, slightly more efficient I think) to remove the dependence on the rather large `expect` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `tr` was buffering the output, and `unbuffer` was being applied only to the `ffmpeg` at the beginning of the command. Which means `unbuffer` was not able to affect the pipe to perl.

This can be fixed using `unbuffer -p` which is for unbuffering piped commands (`<cmd1> | unbuffer -p <cmd2>` unbuffers both `cmd1` and `cmd2`).

However, I also replaced `unbuffer` with `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -eL` to remove the dependence on the `expect` package because it is a large and unnecessary package when `stdbuf` comes as standard. Also, the `-eL` option makes `stdbuf` line buffered which I believe should make it more CPU efficient than not having any buffer at all. The full working code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$i = "test.mkv"; # big file, long encode time
$o = "test.mp4";

open(F, "-|", "ffmpeg -y -i '$i' '$o' 2>&1 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -eL tr '\r' '\n'")
        or die "oh no";

while(<F>) {
        print "A12345: $_"; # some random text so i know the output was processed in perl
}
```

*Since this question was answered in comments and no correct answer was posted I have made this a wiki answer, credit should go to @Borodin*

Comment: Thanks for this. I meant to write a solution, but this is much more useful than what I would have written. You should accept your answer as soon as you can to mark the question closed.

Comment: Ok so, this isn't working for me although I'm running directly from bash, not perl, and I'm piping to sed, not tr.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, output buffering is something performed by the one doing the output.

Most programs buffer their output unless they are connected to a terminal, so unless you have one of the very few programs that provide an option to disable buffering, the only option available is to fool them by using a pseudo-tty instead of a pipe. This is what `unbuffer` does.

The problem in this case is that there are two programs doing output buffering: `ffmpeg` and `tr`. You'll need to convince both to avoid buffering. You need to use `unbuffer` for each one! Hopefully, that will convince them not to buffer.

Unfortunately, `... | unbuffer ...` doesn't work. (I don't know why.) So get rid of `tr` by using [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) instead of `<>`.

```
my $buf = '';
while (1) {
   my $rv = sysread($PIPE, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
   die $! if !defined($rv);
   last if !$rv;

   while ($buf =~ s/^([^\r\n]*)[\r\n]//) {
      my $line = $1;
      print("[$line]\n");
   }
}

print("[$buf]\n") if $buf ne "";
```

Of course, all of this assumes that `ffmpeg` flushes it's buffers after sending a carriage return because `unbuffer` probably won't help with that.  (Of course, if that's the case, `unbuffer` probably isn't needed at all. Simply avoiding `tr` by switching to `sysread` should do the trick.)

Comment: Using `unbuffer ffmpeg -y -i '$i' '$o' 2>&1 | unbuffer tr '\r' '\n'` doesn't give me any output even if I run it in the shell, I even tried `echo "hi" | unbuffer tr '\r' '\n'` and don't get an output, what am I doing wrong? With the echo command it doesn't return, it just outputs nothing and stays running.

Comment: Indeed. (Tested with `echo "hi" | unbuffer perl -pe1` to make sure it had nothing to do with `tr`.) See update.